# In bootstrap form, how to connect "submit" button to database?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, django-forms

I recently started to use this `bootstrap_form` from `django_bootstrap3` package. It's a nightmare... Here is a simplified version of what I want to do:
- I have 2 textboxes for user to enter data
- POST the data to a local database through clicking a "`submit`" button

What I had originally was to have a base_form.html file that store the form such as:

```
{% extends "expense/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="field1" type="text" name="field1" value="{{ field1 }}">
    <input id="field2" type="number" name="field2" value="{{ field2 }}">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then I would just call this form in my `base.html`, everything works, just ugly. Now that I started to use `django_bootstrap3` package, it's great looking, less code, just nothing works. With `django_bootstrap3`, I no longer need the `base_form.html` (it grabs data from forms.py directly), instead I just need to call `{% bootstrap_form form %}` like the following:

```
{% bootstrap_form form %}
{% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-loading-text="Loading...">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
    </button>
{% endbuttons %}
```

However, there is no place for me to say this is a form POST not GET. Also, there is no place for me to say these are all input field, and submit button should actually submit. Right now the behavior is that after I write some data to the field, and click submit button, nothing is posting to the database. The submit button doesn't work at all.

I don't know what I am missing here. I am very new to web development using django and bootstrap framework. Please help.

Comment: You could just use bootstrap css and js files in your assets folder to make your form styled with bootstrap. Just use bootstrap classes to make your form look better Just check this Out http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @AnkitKalia I totally agree with you... This django-bootstrap3 is so useless. The simplification is going beyond the line of convenience, it's painful to use and customize.

Comment: Yup thats why i am saying that go for that link and simply use bootstrap classes its very easy to use.